# How can I tell if IPython is running?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have an IPython notebook. I have a long-running loop that produces no output in one of the code blocks. It's not this, but imagine it was this:

```
for i in range(100):
    time.sleep(2)
```

I started the code block running a while ago, and now I can't tell whether it's finished, or whether it's still running.

All the IPython status bar says at the top is `Last Checkpoint: 23 minutes ago (autosaved)`. There's nothing in the browser tab to show whether it's running code, either.

I don't want to start the next block because I don't know if this block has finished.

And I don't want to stop the kernel and add print statements to this block, because if it's 80% of the way through, I don't want to kill it and restart it!

Is there anything in IPython - either the browser window or the console - that indicates what code is running right now?

Comment: could put in `print` statements

Comment: It doesn't withhold the prompt until it finishes execution of the last command? If your code contains actual processing and not just `time.sleep()`, you can check your computer's CPU usage, look for the Python process, and so on.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yeah, I guess `ps aux | grep ipykernel` will show me if anything is running, thanks. Just surprised there's nothing in the user interface!

Comment: @letsc thanks, that was my first thought, but I don't want to stop the kernel, as the question says.

Answer (score 64):

1. You can see whether code still being executed or not in three places,
   In the top right corner, there will small circle which stays solid till the execution of code completes.

[image]

2. Every cell will have cell number but when that cell being executed it will show `*` instead of a number

[image]

3. In chrome and firefox browsers tabs icon changes from notebook to a clock.

[image]

Comment: Thanks your answer helped me notice that. Do you know what it means to have empty brackets [ ] .. no * in them, no number in them. I do have the solid circle up top.

Comment: @chimpsarehungry I have never seen that but there is one issue reported https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11027

Comment: @Praveena, very helpful. I was trying to run a notebook on handwriting recognition from github and could not figure out if any section is running as the focus shifts to the next on clicking run. I now notice the * and the solid circle

Comment: I get a bug sometimes for long running cells, the icons just suddenly "turn off" and say the notebook is finished running. But the cell is still running...

Comment: @chimpsarehungry The `[*]` will only appear if you executed the cell just now. If you refresh the page or reconnect you won't get the `[*]` (or any output for that cell), but the operation will continue in the background (i.e. variables created, etc.) and be evidenced by the hourglass and dot.

Answer (score 27):

The block of code will have the line number indicator like this `ln[*]`, which means that the block is running:

[image]

**Edit 1:**

There is a bug in Jupyter notebooks and Jupyter lab (formerly known as Ipython notebooks) where refreshing or reopening the notebook will not keep the previous output (which includes `ln[*]`): https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/83

**Edit 2:**

If you are willing to use a library to show if a cell is running (and its progress), I recommend [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) to add progress bars:

*ASCII Bar:* 
[image]

*GUI Bar:*
[image]

Comment: This doesn't reliably happen if the notebook is refreshed though (at least for me).

Comment: not convinced, sometimes it gets stuck and can stay with * forever, that's the point of the question

Comment: I also believe memory management was changed very recently, when I was running memory intensive calculation (on Windows 10) they were used to jam all my computer forcing restart, now it seems there is a memory limit that is never exceeded, however I don't know any more if calculation is still running or it is frozen.

Comment: @musically_ut Do you mean refreshing the page and keeping the output? Because that is an open bug: https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/83

Comment: One thing not mentioned is that the tqdm package requires you to change your code, and wrap your iterations in a tqdm call. Useful if you really need progress bars on iterations, but not so useful for jupyter notebooks lessons etc

Answer (score 15):

look to the right of ipython terminal, there is a circle. if the block is still running you would see a solid circle and when you hover it says "kernel busy"

if there is nothing running, you would see an empty circle and when you hover it says "kernel idle"

Comment: This seems like a good feature but a screen shot would help as I can't find it. And I am not sure what you mean by "ipython terminal". I am running it in a browser, but my jupyter server was launched by a terminal. The only circle I can see doesn't bring up a tooltip when I hover (although it is solid and the star from the previous answer is there).

Comment: @MikeWise check Praveen's response below

Answer (score 2):

Also, in the browser tab (chrome in my case), you see the timer icon when a cell is executing. This is handy if you are in some other tab and want to check the execution status.
[timer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fL5DL.png)